# Outlook - using 2 different email protocols

Tags: email, outlook, smtp, exchange-server, pop3

Not sure if the title is completely correct, however,

I am having an issue where I have 2 email addresses, 1 for work, 1 for personal, On my laptop I have a version of Outlook, When I am at work and connected to their wifi I am connected to the exchange and can only send from my work email (exchange account) however I cannot with my personal mail (POP mail) when Testing account settings, it connects to the Pop server but cannot send anything through SMTP (Port 25, the email provider does not support SSL), And when I'm at home I am able to send from it, but not the exchange(However once I'm home from work I don't want to be dealing with work emails so that's fine)

does anyone have any ideas what could be happening, My best guess is our exchange server at work is using port 25 and is using it exclusively and not letting anything else make a connection through it, would this be correct?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Most companies (and even some ISPs) block port 25 for security reasons. You will need to talk to your IT department to know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with

> My best guess is our exchange server at work is using port 25 and is using it exclusively and not letting anything else make a connection through it

Port 25 is specific to mailer-domains. The mailer's(like google, yahoo) servers listen at port 25 to recieve the mails, for example gmail or rediffmail will have servers which would be running a service on port 25 to accept/send all the mails. Usually as per the company policies they do-not encourage the usage of personal mail ids, so they block the call to the mailers.

Comment: This isn't a large company with policies like that in place, I have full access to the systems and port 25 is open.